Adding support for EV charging
We want to support EV charging at a garage.
Current
There are two buildings. In the one building there are some garages. In the other building is the utility panel that feeds garage. The panel is 100A and has very little continuous load on it, but does have a heat pump and electric water heater on it. There are 6x 20A breakers for the garage building in the utility panel. The conductors run through a 150' 1" PVC pipe, where the pipe is buried for the 60' between the buildings.

Desired
Provide the infrastructure to support EV charging in the garages. We need to be able to load shed EV charging if the load on the utility panel is too high.
Proposal
In my research it seems that 3x 2 AWG wires will fit in that 1" pipe, which would give us 100A @ 240V out to the garages over that distance. We could install a grounding rod at the garage building (I've heard mixed thoughts on if this is acceptable). We could then install three boxes on the garage building:

Something like a DCC-10 (https://rve-usa.com/products/dcc-10/)
A 120V panel for the existing garage load
A 240V panel for the EV load

Since we only have one pipe, my limited research indicates that if we get correctly shielded signal wire (e.g. 600V), we can put 4x 14 AWG wires in the pipe to do load sensing at the utility panel (per the DCC-10 wiring diagram) so that we can shed the EV panel load and not affect the garage panel load.
Limits

It is not cost effective to change the pipe.
We can't overload the existing 100A utility panel.
We can't shed any load but the EV (i.e. the garage door openers can't be part of the shed load).

Does the proposal sound like it would work? What considerations should I keep in mind? What kind of shielding would I need on those control wires? What else have I missed or gotten wrong?
Other considered options

Contacting the utility to put a meter on the back of the garage from the utility access point with a separate service just for the EVs
It looks like the pipe has an access point right on the edge of the building, so maybe we can tap off there for the wiring going to the garage and use the existing pipe.
Tap off the existing meter with the DCC-9 on the building and then trench through the grass to the back of the garage for a sub-panel.

I'm interested to hear thoughts on this too.

I’m voting to close this question because apartment building construction is off topic.

I was referred to post here from another StackExchange site. I'm trying to make sure that nothing gets missed, so I'm DIY planning.

It doesn’t matter what people on another site say. Planning whole-apartment-complex EV charging is out of scope here.

Ok, so where would a question like this be in-scope?

@nobody -- the problem is that EE.SE generally isn't set up to deal with electrician-y stuff (it's not in the wheelhouse of most EEs), and Engineering.SE generally doesn't have a whole lot of resources on tap for this sort of thing either.  (It's awkward, I know.)

How large is each charger?  Why not run a new service direct to the garage?  I.e. what bad thing happens in that case, e.g. confusion in billing, added fees, etc.

EV expert here. No offense but this proposal is bad.  Many errors including assuming EV charging is a "dumb load" like a hot tub.  The DCC is a waste of money.  There are cheaper ways to do this that will allow tenants to get 100 miles a night Off Their Own Meters if you'd prefer that, without adding load to the building.  EV tech is made for applications like this, you just need to get up to speed :)  Way too much to say for 100 words, come over to Reddit r/evcharging. This one will be fun! You'd be amazed how easy it is.

Also, what is up with the 6 20A circuits? Do they have 6 disconnects grouped together in the garage as Code requires?
